# Bootstrap nav-tabs not loading proper page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

After much trial and error and searching I've resorted to asking for helping as I don't know what my issue is at this point. I have an MVC site I am trying to work with and managed to the get nav-tabs to work on screen but they are not switching between the views and thus not loading the content that I want to show. I don't get any errors but I also don't get the proper content even after trying both href setups shown.

Below is my _layout.cshtml page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>    
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="~/Views/Home/Itinerary.cshtml" data-toggle="tab">Itinerary</a></li>            
        </ul>
    </div>    
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
    </div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Below are the 2 views I am trying to tab across using my site but can't actually generate, I keep seeing the home page information:

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";}
<br />
    <h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
    <h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
    
    <p>Home</p>
```

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Itinerary";
}
<br />
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
```

The home controller has the basic setup that comes from creating a new MVC solution so there is nothing fancy there.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Itinerary()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
```

This is on Bootstrap 4.6 as well if that helps.

Comment: I suppose you are trying to load data dynamically inside the tab from your controller?

Answer (score 0):

you should use href="/Controller/Action?Id=parameter".

With your case: href="/Home/Itinerary"

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="~/ContollerName/ViewName">

//your code
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="~/Home/Itinerary" data-toggle="tab">Itinerary</a></li>
```

your can also use this. Remove new para if you have no parameters.

```
a href="@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName", new {Para1 = "", Para2 = ""})"
```